# D3.js rotate axis labels around the middle point

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with D3.js now and even though I found very similar cases I am not really able to put them together and move on.

I have something similar as a radar chart and I would like to append to each ax I create (number of axes is not fixed could be 4, but also 40) text, which I already have, but rotate the text around center point and turn them as soon as they reach 180 degrees, actually 0 degrees.

The result should look like this:

[image]

What I have now is this:

[image]

I only know how to reach this within `arc`, which is also nicely shown [here](http://bl.ocks.org/vigorousnorth/7331bb51d4f0c2ae0314), but I did not really figure it out for my case.

This is my code snippet, where I append those text criteria:

```
//Write criterias
      axis.append("text")
        .attr("class","labels")
        .attr("font-size","12px")
        .attr("font-family","Montserrat")
        .attr("text-anchor","middle") 
        .attr("fill","white")
        .attr("x",function (d, i) {
          return radius * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI/2)*options.circles.labelFactor;
        })
        .attr("y",function (d, i) {
          return radius * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI/2)*options.circles.labelFactor;
        })
        .text(function (d) {
          return d;
        });
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fsb47ndf/

Thank you for any advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people find it difficult to rotate an SVG element, because the `rotate` function of the `transform` attribute rotates the element around the origin (0,0), not around its center:

> If optional parameters  and  are not supplied, the rotate is about the origin of the current user coordinate system ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute))

Thus, an easy option is dropping the `x` and the `y` attributes of the texts, and positioning them using `transform`. That way, we can easily calculate the rotation:

```
.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    var rotate = angleSlice * i > Math.PI / 2 ?
        (angleSlice * i * 180 / Math.PI) - 270 :
        (angleSlice * i * 180 / Math.PI) - 90;
    return "translate(" + radius * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2) * options.circles.labelFactor +
        "," + radius * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2) * options.circles.labelFactor +
        ") rotate(" + rotate + ")"
})
```

Here is your code:

```js
data = [{
   name: 'DATA1',
   value: 22,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA2',
   value: 50,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA3',
   value: 0,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA4',
   value: 24,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA5',
   value: 22,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA6',
   value: 30,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA7',
   value: 20,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA8',
   value: 41,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA9',
   value: 31,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA10',
   value: 30,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA11',
   value: 30,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA12',
   value: 30,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA13',
   value: 30,
 }, {
   name: 'DATA14',
   value: 30,
 }, ];



 var options = {

   width: 600,
   height: 600,

   margins: {
     top: 100,
     right: 100,
     bottom: 100,
     left: 100
   },

   circles: {
     levels: 6,
     maxValue: 100,
     labelFactor: 1.15,
     opacity: 0.2,
   },

 };


 var allAxis = (data.map(function(i, j) {
     return i.name
   })),
   total = allAxis.length,
   radius = Math.min(options.width / 2, options.height / 2),
   angleSlice = Math.PI * 2 / total,
   Format = d3.format('');

 var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain([0, options.circles.maxValue])
   .range([50, radius]);

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", options.width + options.margins.left + options.margins.right)
   .attr("height", options.height + options.margins.top + options.margins.bottom);

 var g = svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + (options.width / 2 + options.margins.left) + "," + (options.height / 2 + options.margins.top) + ")");

 var axisGrid = g.append("g")
   .attr("class", "axisWraper");

 var axis = axisGrid.selectAll(".axis")
   .data(allAxis)
   .enter()
   .append("g")
   .attr("class", "axis")

 //append them lines
 axis.append("line")
   .attr("x1", 0)
   .attr("y1", 0)
   .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
     var tempX2 = radius * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
     return tempX2;
   })
   .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
     var tempY = radius * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
     return tempY;
   })
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("stroke", "black")
   .attr("fill", "none");

 //Draw background circles
 axisGrid.selectAll(".levels")
   .data([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("class", "gridCircle")
   .attr("r", function(d, i) {
     return parseInt(radius / options.circles.levels * d, 10);
   })
   .attr("stroke", "black")
   .attr("fill-opacity", options.circles.opacity);

 //Write data
 axis.append("text")
   .attr("class", "labels")
   .attr("font-size", "12px")
   .attr("font-family", "Montserrat")
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("fill", "black")
   .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
     var rotate = angleSlice * i > Math.PI ? (angleSlice * i * 180 / Math.PI) - 270 : (angleSlice * i * 180 / Math.PI) - 90;
     return "translate(" + radius * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2) * options.circles.labelFactor + "," + radius * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2) * options.circles.labelFactor + ") rotate(" + rotate + ")"
   })
   .text(function(d) {
     return d;
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like already mentioned by Gerardo Furtado in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42643557/4235784) life can get easier if you ditch your `x` and `y` attributes in favor of doing all positioning and rotation via the `transform` attribute. However, you can take his approach even a step further by letting the browser do all the trigonometry. All you need to do is specify a list of appropriate transform definitions.

```
.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
  var angleI = angleSlice  * i * 180 / Math.PI - 90;   // the angle to rotate the label
  var distance = radius * options.circles.labelFactor; // the distance from the center
  var flip = angleI > 90 ? 180 : 0;                    // 180 if label needs to be flipped

  return "rotate(" + angleI + ") translate(" + distance + ")" + "rotate(" + flip + ")");
  //       ^1.^                    ^2.^                           ^3.^
})
```

If you omit the [`x`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextElementXAttribute) and [`y`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextElementYAttribute) attributes, they will default to `0`, which means, that the texts will all start off at the origin. From there it is easy to move and rotate them to their final position applying just three transformations:

1. `rotate` the texts to the angle according to their position on the perimeter
2. `translate` the rotated texts outwards to their final position
3. Flip the texts on the left hand side of the circle using another `rotate`.

Have a look at the following snippet for a working demo:

```js
data = [{
    name: 'DATA1',
    value: 22,
  },
  {
    name: 'DATA2',
    value: 50,
  },
  {
    name: 'DATA3',
    value: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'DATA4',
    value: 24,
  },
  {
    name: 'DATA5',
    value: 22,
  },
  {
    name: 'DATA6',
    value: 30,
  },
  {
    name: 'DATA7',
    value: 20,
  },
  {
    name: 'DATA8',
    value: 41,
  },
  {
    name: 'DATA9',
    value: 31,
  },
  {
    name: 'DATA10',
    value: 30,
  },
  {
    name: 'DATA11',
    value: 30,
  },
  {
    name: 'DATA12',
    value: 30,
  },
  {
    name: 'DATA13',
    value: 30,
  },
  {
    name: 'DATA14',
    value: 30,
  },
];



var options = {

  width: 600,
  height: 600,

  margins: {
    top: 100,
    right: 100,
    bottom: 100,
    left: 100
  },

  circles: {
    levels: 6,
    maxValue: 100,
    labelFactor: 1.15,
    opacity: 0.2,
  },

};


var allAxis = (data.map(function(i, j) {
    return i.name
  })),
  total = allAxis.length,
  radius = Math.min(options.width / 2, options.height / 2),
  angleSlice = Math.PI * 2 / total,
  Format = d3.format('');

var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, options.circles.maxValue])
  .range([50, radius]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", options.width + options.margins.left + options.margins.right)
  .attr("height", options.height + options.margins.top + options.margins.bottom);

var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (options.width / 2 + options.margins.left) + "," + (options.height / 2 + options.margins.top) + ")");

var axisGrid = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axisWraper");

var axis = axisGrid.selectAll(".axis")
  .data(allAxis)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")

//append them lines
axis.append("line")
  .attr("x1", 0)
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
    var tempX2 = radius * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    return tempX2;
  })
  .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
    var tempY = radius * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    return tempY;
  })
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("fill", "none");

//Draw background circles
axisGrid.selectAll(".levels")
  .data([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "gridCircle")
  .attr("r", function(d, i) {
    return parseInt(radius / options.circles.levels * d, 10);
  })
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("fill-opacity", options.circles.opacity);

//Write data
axis.append("text")
  .attr("class", "labels")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-family", "Montserrat")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      var angleI = angleSlice * i * 180 / Math.PI - 90; // the angle to rotate the label
      var distance = radius * options.circles.labelFactor; // the distance from the center
      var flip = angleI > 90 ? 180 : 0; // 180 if label needs to be flipped

      return "rotate(" + angleI + ") translate(" + distance + ")" + "rotate(" + flip + ")"
  })
.text(function(d) {
  console.log(d);
  return d;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice answer, thank you very much, it helped me to solve some similar further hesitations, also the `x` and `y` attributes and how to treat them in such cases is now clarified for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to rotate all the labels. You probably have to adjust the positioning and rotation angle based on exactly how you want it.

```
var angle = 180;

svg.selectAll(".labels")
   .attr("transform", "translate(300,0) rotate("+angle+")");
```

Comment: But this will actually only flip my labels by 180 degrees and shift them further from my svg element. So after all I will have the same result as in the second picture only the labels will be just upside down

Comment: @MatějZmítko You can try with other angle values to get your desired result, 180 is just an example. if you can post your full code in a fiddle, I can take a look at it and fix it.

Comment: So I uploaded my fiddle, you can see edited section of my question. Thanks for any suggestions