# d3.js Radar Chart label rotation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, radar-chart

I am trying to create a radar chart with labels rotated along the radar lines, like in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3ANM.png

Current code:

```
    axis.append("text")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .text(function(d){return d})
    .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .style("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", "1.5em")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i){return "translate(0, -10)";})
    .attr("x", function(d, i){return w/2*(1- factorLegend*Math.sin(i*radians/total))-60*Math.sin(i*radians/total);})
    .attr("y", function(d, i){return h/2*(1-Math.cos(i*radians/total))-20*Math.cos(i*radians/total);});
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you observed that there is a **90** degree **rotation** difference in what you have and what you want. for some cases you have to use -90

Comment: Hey rioV8, I'm really sorry, the image was wrong. I have updated it. It is a bit more complicated than that, I would say.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42643557/1675954

Comment: you might also find this link about [rotated axis labels](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4403522) interesting (but in the link it's not applied to a radar chart, check out the SO answer for that)..

Comment: Thanks Rachel, the links are helpful! I havent seen the question when I searched for similar issues. I am also thinking of using the text-on-path option, it is much easier than the rotation.