# How to plot animatable points on a radar chart where gaps exist in the data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3.js but I'm attempting to create a radar chart. The radar chart will be fed data in real time, where, upon receiving the data, it will then be plotted on the chart incrementally. The incremental addition should be transitioned, similarly to that of an SVG stroke transition — the data itself may have missing values, however, which is causing some issues.

I was hoping somebody may have some answers, or help, to the below (see example [code](https://codepen.io/Numiko/pen/WNmxJWX??editors=0110) for reference):

- If you click the button to update the chart with missing data, you'll notice that the first and last point no longer connect. I imagine this is because it's now 2 line segments, but is there a way to make these connect?
- Relatedly, if you use the button to incrementally add new data, when you fill the entire chart out, the transition is odd — presumably because the number of plots has changed, and because I've had to change the curve type depending on whether we have all the data or not. Is there a nicer way to achieve this?

I have tried:

- Plotting missing data values with arbitrary values so that there's always one line segment; I then attempted to make the arbitrary path hidden, although I wasn't able to achieve this.

In essence, I would like to be able to add / remove / update new data to the chart dynamically and ensure the transition between those states behaves as though it's one line — which ensures the curve and behaviour is consistent.

Code:

```
function RadarChart(id, data, options) {
  var cfg = {
    w: 600, //Width of the circle
    h: 600, //Height of the circle
    margin: 30, //The margins of the SVG
    levels: 3, //How many levels or inner circles should there be drawn
    maxValue: 0, //What is the value that the biggest circle will represent
    labelFactor: 1.1, //How much farther than the radius of the outer circle should the labels be placed
    wrapWidth: 10000, //The number of pixels after which a label needs to be given a new line
    opacityArea: 0.35, //The opacity of the area of the blob
    dotRadius: 4, //The size of the colored circles of each blog
    opacityCircles: 0.1, //The opacity of the circles of each blob
    strokeWidth: 2, //The width of the stroke around each blob
    roundStrokes: false, //If true the area and stroke will follow a round path (cardinal-closed)
    color: d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10) //Color function
  };

  //Put all of the options into a variable called cfg
  if ("undefined" !== typeof options) {
    for (var i in options) {
      if ("undefined" !== typeof options[i]) {
        cfg[i] = options[i];
      }
    } //for i
  } //if

  //If the supplied maxValue is smaller than the actual one, replace by the max in the data
  // var maxValue = Math.max(
  //   cfg.maxValue,
  //   d3.max(data, function (i) {
  //     return d3.max(
  //       i.map(function (o) {
  //         return o.value;
  //       })
  //     );
  //   })
  // );

  //   This should be dynamic in case no 5s are added?
  var maxValue = 5;

  // Current rotation offset
  var offset = 0;

  var allAxis = data[0].map(function (i, j) {
    return i.axis;
  }); //Names of each axis
  var total = allAxis.length; //The number of different axes
  var radius = Math.min(cfg.w / 2, cfg.h / 2); //Radius of the outermost circle
  var Format = d3.format(""); //Percentage formatting
  var angleSlice = (Math.PI * 2) / total; //The width in radians of each "slice"

  //Scale for the radius
  var rScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([100, radius]).domain([0, 5]);
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////////// Create the container SVG and g /////////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //Remove whatever chart with the same id/class was present before
  d3.select(id).select("svg").remove();

  //Initiate the radar chart SVG
  var svg = d3
    .select(id)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", cfg.w + cfg.margin + cfg.margin)
    .attr("height", cfg.h + cfg.margin + cfg.margin)
    .attr("class", "radar" + id);

  //Append a g element
  var g = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr(
      "transform",
      "translate(" +
        (cfg.w / 2 + cfg.margin) +
        "," +
        (cfg.h / 2 + cfg.margin) +
        ")"
    );

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /////////////// Draw the Circular grid //////////////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //Wrapper for the grid & axes
  var axisGrid = g.append("g").attr("class", "axisWrapper");

  //Draw the background circles
  axisGrid
    .selectAll(".levels")
    .data(d3.range(1, cfg.levels + 1).reverse())
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "gridCircle")
    .attr("r", function (d, i) {
      var scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 5]).range([100, radius]);
      return scale(d);
      // return (radius / cfg.levels) * d;
    })
    .style("fill", "transparent")
    .style("stroke", "#fff")
    .style("stroke-width", "2px");

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////////////////// Draw the axes //////////////////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //Create the straight lines radiating outward from the center
  var axis = axisGrid
    .selectAll(".axis")
    .data(allAxis)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis");

  //Append the lines
  axis
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", function (d, i) {
      return rScale(maxValue * 0.2) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .attr("y1", function (d, i) {
      return rScale(maxValue * 0.2) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .attr("x2", function (d, i) {
      return rScale(maxValue * 1.1) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .attr("y2", function (d, i) {
      return rScale(maxValue * 1.1) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    })
    .attr("class", "line")
    .style("stroke", "#fff")
    .style("stroke-dasharray", "5px")
    .style("stroke-width", "2px");

  //Append the labels at each axis
  axis
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .style("font-size", "8px")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581308/d3-js-rotate-axis-labels-around-the-middle-point
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
      var angleI = (angleSlice * i * 180) / Math.PI - 90; // the angle to rotate the label
      var distance = radius * cfg.labelFactor; // the distance from the center
      var flip = angleI > 90 ? 90 : 90; // 180 if label needs to be flipped

      return (
        "rotate(" +
        angleI +
        ") translate(" +
        distance +
        ")" +
        "rotate(" +
        flip +
        ")"
      );
    })
    .text(function (d) {
      return d;
    })
    .call(wrap, cfg.wrapWidth);

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ///////////// Draw the radar chart blobs & lines ////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //Create the outlines
  var radius = (cfg.h - cfg.margin * 2) / 2;

  var lineRadial = d3
    .lineRadial()
    .curve(d3.curveCardinalClosed)
    .radius((d) => rScale(d.value))
    .defined((d) => d.value)
    .angle((d, i) => (i * Math.PI * 2) / 12);

  var lineRadialOpen = d3
    .lineRadial()
    .curve(d3.curveCardinal)
    .defined((d) => d.value)
    .radius((d) => rScale(d.value))
    .angle((d, i) => (i * Math.PI * 2) / 12);

  //Create a wrapper for the blobs and lines
  var blobWrapper = g.append("g").attr("class", "radarWrapper");

  this.update = function (data) {
    //Set up your path as normal
    var path = blobWrapper
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(data)
      .join("path")
      .attr("class", "radarStroke")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(" + (-offset * 180) / Math.PI + ")")
      .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .attr("d", (d, i) => {
        // Only close the path if all items have been filled in
        const shouldClosePath = d.every((item) => {
          return item.value;
        });

        if (shouldClosePath) return lineRadial(d);

        return lineRadialOpen(d);
      })
      .style("stroke-width", cfg.strokeWidth + "px")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .style("transform", "scale(1)")
      .style("stroke", function (d, i) {
        return cfg.color(i);
      });
  };

  this.update(data);

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /////////////////// Helper Function /////////////////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //Taken from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321
  //Wraps SVG text
  function wrap(text, width) {
    text.each(function () {
      var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.4, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        x = text.attr("x"),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y);

      while ((word = words.pop())) {
        line.push(word);
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
          line.pop();
          tspan.text(line.join(" "));
          line = [word];
          tspan = text
            .append("tspan")
            .attr("x", x)
            .attr("y", y)
            .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
            .text(word);
        }
      }
    });
  } //wrap
} //RadarChart

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// Set-Up //////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////// Data //////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var data = [
  [
    { axis: "A", value: 5 },
    { axis: "B", value: 3 },
    { axis: "C", value: 3 },
    { axis: "D", value: 4 },
    { axis: "E", value: 2 },
    { axis: "F", value: 3 },
    { axis: "G", value: 4 },
    { axis: "H", value: 5 },
    { axis: "I", value: 3 },
    { axis: "J", value: 2 },
    { axis: "K", value: 3 },
    { axis: "L", value: 4 }
  ],
  [
    { axis: "A", value: 3 },
    { axis: "B", value: 2 },
    { axis: "C", value: 1 },
    { axis: "D", value: 4 },
    { axis: "E", value: 3 },
    { axis: "F", value: 5 },
    { axis: "G", value: 2 },
    { axis: "H", value: 4 },
    { axis: "I", value: 4 },
    { axis: "J", value: 5 },
    { axis: "K", value: 3 },
    { axis: "L", value: 4 }
  ]
];

var dataMissingPlots = [
  [
    { axis: "A", value: 2 },
    { axis: "B", value: 1 },
    { axis: "C", value: 5 },
    { axis: "D", value: null },
    { axis: "E", value: 2 },
    { axis: "F", value: 2 },
    { axis: "G", value: 5 },
    { axis: "H", value: 3 },
    { axis: "I", value: 2 },
    { axis: "J", value: 1 },
    { axis: "K", value: 3 },
    { axis: "L", value: 2 }
  ]
];

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////// Draw the Chart //////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var color = d3
  .scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
  .range(["red", "green", "#blue", "red", "green", "pink", "orange"]);

var radarChartOptions = {
  w: 600,
  h: 600,
  margin: 100,
  maxValue: 5,
  levels: 5,
  color: color
};
//Call function to draw the Radar chart
const chart = new RadarChart(".radarChart", data, radarChartOptions);

document.querySelector("#drawMissing").addEventListener("click", () => {
  chart.update(dataMissingPlots);
});

const incrementData = [
  [
    { axis: "A", value: 2 },
    { axis: "B", value: null },
    { axis: "C", value: null },
    { axis: "D", value: null },
    { axis: "E", value: null },
    { axis: "F", value: null },
    { axis: "G", value: null },
    { axis: "H", value: null },
    { axis: "I", value: null },
    { axis: "J", value: null },
    { axis: "K", value: null },
    { axis: "L", value: null }
  ]
];

document.querySelector("#increment").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const nextIndex = incrementData[0].findIndex((item) => {
    return !item.value;
  });

  incrementData[0][nextIndex].value = randomInteger(1, 5);

  chart.update(incrementData);
});

function randomInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: so when you have data null, what do you want, to do: fix a value?, or eliminate the point? if you want to fix value, what value do you want to set?

Comment: It's tricky. At first I tried eliminating the points that were undefined using D3s `.defined()` method. This worked in that it hid those points and I was able to plot the chart, but having gaps in the data — for example, when clicking the "Draw new plot with missing data" button in the example code — meant that I could no longer use the same curve type to join the first and last points... if that makes sense?

Comment: what i'll do its to  take the middle value..